# How to filter out magnesium acetate (a soluble salt) quickly and cheaply from water

Tags: acid-base, aqueous-solution, solubility, solutions

I am conducting an experiment that involves reacting a weak acid and a weak base to form water and a salt with this overall equation

$$\ce{Mg(OH)2(s) + 2CH3COOH(l) <=> 2H2O(l) + Mg(CH3COO)2(aq)}$$
Currently, I am trying to filter out the salt to purify the water; however, there are specific restrictions.

The filtration process must be able to:

- be done quickly. I can't wait a long time for the water to be distilled
- be done at home. This filtration needs to be something that the average person can  could do with household ingredients or ingredients they can buy at a drug store (Assume that the $\ce{Mg(CH3COO)2}$ solution is given to them pre-made)

So far, I have tried to use Gelatin as a [clarifying agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarifying_agent), which is typically used to [clear beer](http://bertusbrewery.blogspot.com/2012/06/how-to-clear-your-beer-with-gelatin.html). However, I couldn't find much info on using gelatin with salt water. Does anyone have any insight about using gelatin as a [clarifying agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarifying_agent) in this solution? Is there a better way to do such a thing that still meets the requirements?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, so I'm not sure if this will help, but have you considered ion-exchange? You can't *filter* something soluble, but something like ion-exchange resin is pretty easy to come by and is very fast and effective at removing soluble salts.

Comment: it seems like [ion-exchange resin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion-exchange_resin) beads would work. Where could someone buy some of these beads? What [type of resin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion-exchange_resin#Types_of_resins) would I use to remove this specific salt? Will it remove the Magnesium and Acetate ions completely or replace them with Sodium ions?

Comment: Actually, I found [this pdf](http://www.lenntech.com/Data-sheets/Ion-Exchange-for-Dummies-RH.pdf) showing that I can use a cation and anion resin beads. All that remains is where I could find such a thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ion-exchange resin can be made with $\ce{H+}$ cations on one type of resin and $\ce{OH-}$ anions on another type of resin. These would leave the water without the any of the magnesium or acetate ions effectively without replacing the ions with other ions. This is how we deionize for general chemical use. This happens according to the reactions below:
$$\ce{2HSO3R + Mg^{2+} + 2C2H3O2- -> Mg(SO3R)2 + 2HC2H3O2}$$
$$\ce{R4N+OH- + HC2H3O2 -> [R4N+ +\ C2H3O2^{-}] + H2O}$$
In these examples, the sulfonates/sulfonic acids and ammonium cations are tethered to the resin so that they can't dissolve.

The downside to this is that if you are trying to measure something else in the system, if it is ionic, it will be removed as well.

I've never had to source ion-exchange resin myself, so I'm not sure of the easiest way to go about it. There's pleanty of [deionization resin](http://smile.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=deionization%20resin&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Adeionization%20resin) on Amazon. The [mixed stuff](http://smile.amazon.com/Resintech-MBD-30-Nuclear-Grade-Mixed/dp/B000X92KOC/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1461562301&sr=8-1&keywords=deionization%20resin) is simple to use, just mix it with your water, agitate for a while and then filter it out and you'll have removed all the ions. That is expensive, though, because it's single use.

You can also buy [regeneratable](https://www.uswatersystems.com/aries-cg10-resin.html?fee=10&fep=3067&gclid=CjwKEAjw3fG4BRDsn9GAv7T2zEkSJACNJdjgsyvGxyMlhgNWtrFdGx826fYzKnTFuDirMHRqqiU8UhoCF6Hw_wcB) ion [exchange resins](http://www.servapure.com/USF-Brand-Resin-A-674OH-Strong-Base-Type-I-Anion-in-OH-Form_p_5536.html). You don't want to mix the regeneratable stuff, and you have to do two separate ion-exchange steps, one with the cation-exchange and one with the anion-exchange. It's pretty easy to regenerate, though, as far as I know. You just use strong acid with the cation-exchange to redissolve the soluble cations and use a hydroxide solution to regenerate the anion exchange resin. It can't be done forever because there are some cations and anions that just won't want to redissolve, but if you're doing it a lot, might be worth it. I can't seem to find the anion stuff except in bulk.

I'm guessing the mixed type would be more appropriate for most applications. **If you really need it quickly, I think you can buy the filters at Lowes/Home Depot and just run it through those or open them up and get the resin out.**

**Update:** [These filters](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Zero-Water-8-Cup-Pitcher-ZD-013D/202638785) are the only ones I saw that said they actually have the "dual ion-exchange system." [Their website](https://www.zerowater.com/8c-blue-pitcher) actually says it gets down to "000 total dissolved solids," which is pretty impressive relative to other water filters from what I've seen (depending on what "000 TDS" actually means).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solves the finding the resin part. Also, at first your equation seemed confusing to me compared to what i found [here](http://www.lenntech.com/Data-sheets/Ion-Exchange-for-Dummies-RH.pdf), but I then realized that the water from the second equation comes from the hydroxide and hydrogen ions from the resin beads. I'm still confused on which type of cation and anion resin beads would be best to use, but i think It would be better to use one that doesn't need filtering, since **the pitcher won't work well** since every person who wants to replicate this has to spend $20 extra

Comment: If the pitcher is the only possible and/or most efficient way, it might work, but is there anyway to use the resins without filtration? Could I just use beads that exchange the ions (if they're not too hard to come by) and then filter them out with filter paper?

Comment: @Abob78 That's exactly what my students do, all they do is put the resin in a vial with the water, shake it up and decant it off. Works fine. The beads aren't like grains of sand or anything, they're pretty easy to get out. The "mixed bed" resin I linked above should work, but I just don't think its as readily available at a local store. Could be wrong, but I didn't find anything online. If I were in a pinch, I'd use the filter pitcher or, because I'm destructive, I'd gut the filter, see how much was in one and decide if it was practical to do that way.

Comment: Central Pennsylvania water is *really* hard, some of the hardest water in the country, apparently. These ion exchange beads soften the water to the point that we can't even get a reading for calcium or magnesium ions in the water by atomic absorption.

Comment: do you happen to know where I could buy ion exchange resin **beads** containing OH- and H+ in stores? I've found some online but they go for hundreds of dollars because they come in bulk amounts (more than 1 lb).

Comment: @Abob78 I can't find any in stores. [This stuff](http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B000X92KOC/ref=mp_s_a_1_1?qid=1461957344&sr=8-1&pi=SY200_QL40&keywords=deionization+resin&dpPl=1&dpID=51cnUsOEdQL&ref=plSrch) was the best I could find. In-stores is tough, that's why I said about the filters and how I would just dismantle one if I needed it on short notice.

Comment: I specifically could buy them online, I'm talking about if a student wanted to do this at home. By in store, I meant something readily available. Most of what I've seen goes for hundreds of dollars in bulk meant for industrial use. If there's something cheaper and possible smaller scale, even if it's online, it would be great. They don't even have to be beads or reusable, I just thought that beads would just be preferred.

Comment: @Abob78 As I said, I can't find them in stores beyond what I've already told you.

Comment: Okay, then how much of the disposable mixed stuff would i need to get rid of, let's say, 14.2g (.1 moles) of Mg(CH3COO)2 in 360 mL [or grams] (.2 moles) of water?